# How to prevent stack plots repeating plots?

Tags: matplotlib, space, subplot, data-science

I have a code that should produce two different graphs and place them into one image and cannot figure out why it returns the last mentioned graph twice. The code is as follows:

```
import spacepy as sp
from spacepy import pycdf
from pylab import *
from spacepy.toolbox import windowMean, normalize
from spacepy.plot.utils import annotate_xaxis
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from matplotlib.dates import DayLocator, HourLocator, MinuteLocator
from matplotlib import rc, rcParams
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
import bisect as bi
import seaborn as sea
import sys
import os
import multilabel as ml
import pandas as pd

sea.set_context('poster')
# sea.set_style('ticks',{'axes.facecolor':'yellow'})
sea.set_style('whitegrid')
sea.set_palette('muted',color_codes=True)
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', family='Mono')
rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r'\usepackage{amsmath}']

MMS_1_HPCA_SURVEY_ION = pycdf.CDF(r'/home/ary/Desktop/Arya/Project/Data/MMS/1/HPCA/Survey/Ion/mms1_hpca_srvy_l2_ion_20151025120000_v1.0.0.cdf')

EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1 = MMS_1_HPCA_SURVEY_ION['Epoch'][...]
H_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1 = MMS_1_HPCA_SURVEY_ION['mms1_hpca_hplus_flux'][...]
O_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1 = MMS_1_HPCA_SURVEY_ION['mms1_hpca_oplus_flux'][...]
Ion_Energy_SURVEY_ION_1 = MMS_1_HPCA_SURVEY_ION['mms1_hpca_ion_energy'][...]

MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time = dt.datetime(2015, 10, 25, 12, 0, 0, 908117)
MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time = dt.datetime(2015, 10, 25, 16, 22, 24, 403623)

dt_MMS = dt.timedelta(seconds = 15)

plt.close('all')

fig_MMS, axs_MMS = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
cmap = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
cmap.set_bad('black')

sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION = bi.bisect_left(EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1,MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time)
sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION = int(sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION-(sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION/100))
lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION = bi.bisect_left(EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1, MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time)
lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION = int(lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION+((len(EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1)-lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION)/100))

if MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time.date() == MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time.date():
    stopfmt = '%H:%M'
else:
    stopfmt = '%-m/%-d/%y %H:%M'

title_1 = MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')+' -'+MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time.strftime(stopfmt)

if dt_MMS.seconds !=0:
    title_1 = title_1 + ' with '+str(dt_MMS.seconds)+' second time averaging'

for j, ax in enumerate(axs_MMS.T.flatten()):
    flix_1 = np.array(H_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION, 
                                          j, :].T)

    if dt_MMS==dt.timedelta(0):
        fluxwin_1 = flix_1
        timewin_1 = EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION]
    else:
        fluxwin_1=[[0 for y in range(len(flix_1))] for x_1 in range(len(flix_1))]
        for i, flox in enumerate(flix_1):
            fluxwin_1[i], timewin_1 = windowMean(flox, EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION],
                                                 winsize=dt_MMS, overlap=dt.timedelta(0))
            fluxwin_1[i] = np.array(fluxwin_1[i])
            for x_1 in np.where(np.diff(EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION])
                    >dt.timedelta(hours=1))[0]+sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:
                fluxwin_1[i][bi.bisect_right(timewin_1, EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[x_1]):bi.bisect_right(timewin_1, 
                                                                                               EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[x_1+1])]=0
        fluxwin_1 = np.array(fluxwin_1)

    fluxwin_1[np.where(fluxwin_1<=0)] = 0

    x_1 = mdates.date2num(timewin_1)

    pax_1 = ax.pcolormesh(x_1, Ion_Energy_SURVEY_ION_1, fluxwin_1, shading='turkey',cmap=cmap, vmin=1, 
                          vmax=np.nanmax(H_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION,:,:]), 
                          norm=LogNorm())

    sax_1 = ax.twinx()
    plt.setp(sax_1.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    sax_1.tick_params(axis='y', right='off')
    ax.set_xlim(MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time, MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time)
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.set_yticks([10, 100, 1000,10000])
    #Allows non-log formatted values to be used for ticks
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter())

axs_MMS[0].set_ylabel('Energy (eV)')
axs_MMS[0].set_title(title_1)

for j, ax in enumerate(axs_MMS.T.flatten()):
    flix_2 = np.array(O_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION, 
                                          j, :].T)

    if dt_MMS==dt.timedelta(0):
        fluxwin_2 = flix_2
        timewin_2 = EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_2[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION]
    else:
        fluxwin_2=[[0 for y in range(len(flix_2))] for x_2 in range(len(flix_2))]
        for i, flox in enumerate(flix_2):
            fluxwin_2[i], timewin_2 = windowMean(flox, EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION],
                                                 winsize=dt_MMS, overlap=dt.timedelta(0))
            fluxwin_2[i] = np.array(fluxwin_2[i])
            for x_2 in np.where(np.diff(EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION])
                    >dt.timedelta(hours=1))[0]+sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:
                fluxwin_2[i][bi.bisect_right(timewin_2, EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[x_2]):bi.bisect_right(timewin_2, 
                                                                                               EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[x_1+1])]=0
        fluxwin_2 = np.array(fluxwin_2)

    fluxwin_2[np.where(fluxwin_2<=0)] = 0

    x_2 = mdates.date2num(timewin_2)

    pax_2 = ax.pcolormesh(x_2, Ion_Energy_SURVEY_ION_1, fluxwin_2, shading='turkey',cmap=cmap, vmin=1, 
                          vmax=np.nanmax(O_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION,:,:]), 
                          norm=LogNorm())

    sax_2 = ax.twinx()
    plt.setp(sax_2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    sax_2.tick_params(axis='y', right='off')
    ax.set_xlim(MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time, MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time)
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.set_yticks([10, 100, 1000,10000])
    #Allows non-log formatted values to be used for ticks
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter())

axs_MMS[1].set_ylabel('Energy (eV)')

cbar_ax_1 = fig_MMS.add_axes([0.93, 0.15, 0.02, 0.7])

cb_MMS_1 = fig_MMS.colorbar(pax_1, cax=cbar_ax_1)
cb_MMS_1.set_label(r'Counts sec$^{-1}$ ster$^{-1}$ cm$^{-2}$ keV$^{-1}$')
#Sets the colorbar value range
cb_MMS_1.set_clim(1, np.nanmax(H_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION,:,:]))
#Redraws the colorbar
cb_MMS_1.draw_all()
```

and the image returned looks as such:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPDdk.png)

Comment: I think you need to understand the concept of a [mcve]. This code is not minimal (much too long, too many unnecessary details), and it is not comple or verifiable, since it makes excesive use of unavailable external data.

Comment: There are many things you have to weigh in when you start taking in data from quasi reliable sources. There are faults with every data file that must be taken into account and if not could jeopardize the integrity of a research project. Taking extra steps to verify if the data is correct or taking extra steps in correcting data is a must in the field of data science. In programming I do understand the idea of simplicity, however, this is not the case.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the necessity to provide a [mcve] when discussing an issue in a code. Of course you should not take any (unreliable) external data, but provide the necessary data yourself (like I did in my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example which corresponds to your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True, figsize=(4,2.4))

for j, ax in enumerate(axs.T.flatten()):
    x_1 = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]
    y_1 = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
    z_1 = [[6,5,4],[2,3,4],[6,5,4]]

    pax_1 = ax.pcolormesh(x_1, y_1, z_1)

axs[0].set_ylabel('Energy (eV)')
axs[0].set_title("Title1")

for j, ax in enumerate(axs.T.flatten()):
    x_2 = [[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5]]
    y_2 = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
    z_2 = [[2,1,2],[2,1,2],[2,1,2]]

    pax_2 = ax.pcolormesh(x_2, y_2, z_2)

axs[1].set_ylabel('Energy (eV)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here you plot each plot both axes.

Instead you need to plot to the different axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True, figsize=(4,2.4))

x_1 = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]
y_1 = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
z_1 = [[6,5,4],[2,3,4],[6,5,4]]

pax_1 = axs[0].pcolormesh(x_1, y_1, z_1)

axs[0].set_ylabel('Energy (eV)')
axs[0].set_title("Title1")

x_2 = [[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5]]
y_2 = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
z_2 = [[2,1,2],[2,1,2],[2,1,2]]

pax_2 = axs[1].pcolormesh(x_2, y_2, z_2)

axs[1].set_ylabel('Energy (eV)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Basically the solution was to take the pcolormesh out of the `for` loop and put the appropriate sub axis position